# converting plain text into json

Tags: javascript, json, bash

Suppose I have a text file that I want to convert into json file. Precisely, I want to convert each line `$line` to `"$line":"someid"` . Is there a proper way to do that using bash script langage or `javascript`.

For example

```
I want to
convert
text into
json
```

would output

```
{{"I want to":"1"},{"convert","2"},{"text into":"3"},{"json":"4"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do your expected output like that because you will produce a syntax error, but you can put multiple objects in an *array* instead. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="id">
I want to
convert
text into
json
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var textArr = document.querySelector('#id').innerHTML.split('\n');

function produceJSON(textArr) {
  var arr = [];

  // we loop from 1 to 1 less than the length because
  // the first two elements are empty due to the way the split worked
  for (var i = 1, l = text.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[text[i]] = i;
    arr.push(obj);
  }
  return JSON.stringify(arr);
}

var json = produceJSON(textArr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hy2ke5tu/)