# AngularJS plain text parse with some simple rules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing, plaintext

I have a `.txt` file with some data. I fetch the data with angular `$http` service. But the problem is that the data isn't in `json` format, but has some **basic rules** that I can convert it into `json`.

Here is an example of the data: (I write just first line, the other lines are similar to the first one)

There are 12 quotes with some data.

```
"123456789","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data"
```

After the above line, a new line starts with similar structure.

How can I **parse** it to a data-interchange format like `json`? See the similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284778/converting-plain-text-into-json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it into an array of values using `split`.

```
var text = '"123456789","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data"';

text = text.split(',');
console.log(text);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/1roafj0j/)

Comment: Thank you very much. But there is a problem in your solution. You put it into array, and for example I can print number 2 with text[2], But about text part, I don't konw how many characters does it have.

Comment: uh? no you can print each value by its key number starting from 0 so array[0] will be "123456789" while array[3] will be "some data"

Comment: No, it's not working as you say. Each index is a single character, not the whole string.

Comment: you need to add the split to a variable I forgot it https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/1roafj0j/

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. And there is another problem, for second data stream, there is no , separator. It starts in new line. What should I do for that?

Comment: newline is a character you can use as separator like any one `split('\n')` should work

Comment: Thank you. First I used `split('\n')` then , foreach item, I used `split(',')`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var elements = JSON.parse('["123456789","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data","some data"]');
console.dir(elements);
```

This has the advantage that it correctly parses values containing commas ",".